Type hints for a callable taking a subclass type as argument
A and B are sub-classes of Sup. These functions are defined:
def get_A_report(a: A) -> int

def get_B_report(b: B) -> int

What are the correct typing hints for f?
f = {
    A: get_A_report,
    B: get_B_report,
}

Note: the naive:
f: Dict[Type[Sup],Callable[[Sup],int]]

results in this error:
error: Dict entry 0 has incompatible type
error: Dict entry 1 has incompatible type

I tried to use TypeVar and Protocol, with no success.
Dict entry 0 has incompatible type


btw, you might be interested rather in just functools.singledispatch

@KamilCuk indeed a good suggestion.

Posting as comments because I don't really have a solution without knowing your specific goal. That said, problem #1: functions are contravariant in their argument types. That means f[k] = g is only valid if g's argument type is a supertype of Sup, not a subtype like A or B.

Problem #2: if your goal is to ensure that f[k]'s argument type is the same as k itself, the only way Python provides to match the type of f[k] to the value k itself is to use a TypedDict, which only works with string keys.
